# Conditional Coloring for primefaces datatable on load

Tags: primefaces, colors, datatable, conditional-statements

I have two ArrayList List A and List B of say Employee object my Employee object has 2 attributes say age and name. Now there are certain conditions on the basis of which i have to color my datatable rows,like.

1)Compare both the ArrayList and if the object are same i have to show them with blue color
2)If objects are different(NonMatching) then i have to show them with gray color
3)If List A  has extra elements which are not present in List B(Missing) then i have to show it in red color.

All this colors should be applied on Page load itself.

How to achieve this.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented in quite a few ways. How I would do is create a String field in the Employee object say called color. And in your Java code run FOR loops to compare the 2 Employee Object Lists. And based on the computation add the expected color name into the variable color. In Primefaces datatable use the rowStyleClass='color:{row.color}' to display the color you want. Or you could add a style sheet entry for each color name and map it to rowStyleClass. Hope this helps.